# Allow customer to pay statement (arbitrary amount)

Tags: payment, invoice

Assuming I have a business where dealers can buy on credit, what would be the best way to have them pay their statement via Magento?

In other words: how should I go about charging a customer an arbitrary amount.

One option is to have an observer create a virtual product which has the same price as the statement, this way it could just be 'added to cart', the product would then be deleted once payment is collected.

The issues with this is:

- Other users could potentially see the product (not a good UX idea)
- There's a lot of creation and deleting of non essential data (we really shouldn't have to create a product)
- Statements are not products (and probably should not be 'added to cart')

If anyone has some other ideas, please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a product which is 1$ worth and define the amount of money over the qty. If you need more granularity you could allow numeric qty. Having a product which is only 1 cent worth is hard to handle, because to have 1$ you already need 100 pieces.

If you set the visibility to "not visible at all", you can only add the product by an observer or something, so there is no UX problem.

And because you only have a single product, you don't have to delete and create products at all.

Comment: Definitely some good thoughts here + 1 on the 'not visible at all' part

Comment: What would happen if two dealers want to pay at the same time, wouldn't the product change prices (causing one to pay the wrong amount)?

Comment: if both dealers have the product in cart one of them 10 pieces to pay 10$ and the other 123 pieces to pay 123$? No. - But I think I didn't get the problem ;)

Comment: thanks for explaining, misunderstood some of your solution ;)